# Linux/AM3352: setting gpio via sysfs seem not working

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, gpio, sysfs

I have a board based on the beagle bone black.

I have gpio that should do a hardware reset to the board (gpio117 = gpio3_21)

While in the u-boot it is working - I am doing

> gpio clr 117

(set 0 causes the reset) and does **get hardware reset**

I the Linux, I am doing the following:

> echo 117 > /sys/class/gpio/export
>
> echo high > /sys/class/gpio/gpio117/direction
>
> echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio117/value

And I **get nothing**

Am I doing wrong?

Do I need to change something in the kernel code? in the dts? in defconfig?

Comment: Which distribution are you running and which version of it? Also which kernel version is this?

Comment: As a side note, direction should be "out" not "high"

Comment: @ocirocir, thanks for the note - but for your information, you can put "high" or "low" to "direction"; thus, you can configure direction and put value in one action (you can try it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was in the pinmux mcasp0_ahclkx
In the boneblack dts it was configured:
AM33XX_IOPAD(0x9ac, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE0) /* mcasp0_ahcklx. */

I changed it to:
AM33XX_IOPAD(0x9ac, PIN_OUTPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE7) /* mcasp0_ahcklx.GPIO3_21 */

In the u-boot, it did work because the default is mux 7 (gpio3_21)